# use variable with grep

Tags: bash, variables, syntax, grep

I am trying to extract values from email header, as the Message ID

The grep do not properly use the previous variable...

Here is my code:

```
for email in $1/*.eml
do

MSGID=$(cat ${email} | grep -i 'Message-ID:' |awk '{print $2}')
M=$(echo "\""${MSGID}"\"")
SRV="/var/log/maillog"
echo "${M}"

VER=$(grep -i ${M} ${SRV} | tail -n 1)
echo ${VER}
done
```

I am trying to re-encapsule the initial variable MSGID with M variable; Unfortunately I still could not figure this out.

Initial value (input) looks like this:

```
Message-ID: <COMPUTER123DDF38c28d5e776e4fbdb82e2e92bd9a4373@computer123ddf>
```

The `MSGID` keep only the string as:

```
<COMPUTER123DDF38c28d5e776e4fbdb82e2e92bd9a4373@computer123ddf>
```

Then I would like to use this string against a file using `grep`. Unfortunately the `VER` command does not trigger anything.

I thought that adding `"\""${MSGID}"\""` would/should have keep the initial string untouched.

Comment: There are a lot of redundant steps in this script. Please [edit] your question to provide a sample of your input and the desired output.

Comment: Please show some input file together with your expected output. Maybe it is worth not making your current script the starting point, since for example `awk` may handle it in a way straight-forward way.

Comment: Probably `MSGID=$awk '/^Message-ID:/ {print $2}' file)` would be faster. Also, note `SRV` can be declared outside the `for` loop, since it is a fixed value.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear what you are attempting to accomplish, but just removing the weird stuff simplifies to a script which might help you finish your task.

```
SRV="/var/log/maillog"
for email in $1/*.eml; do
    M=$(awk 'tolower($0) ~ /message-id:/ {print $2}' "$email")
    echo "$M"
    grep -i "$M" "$SRV" | tail -n 1
done
```

This has a number of problematic corner cases.  The Message-Id extraction should probably be stricter:

```
M=$(awk 'tolower($1) ~ /^message-id:/ { print $2 } /^$/ { exit(0) }' "$email")
```

and if the extracted Message-Id contains regex metacharacters, you should escape them, or perhaps use proper `grep` flags:

```
grep -iF "$M" "$SRV" | tail -n 1
```

To be sure, the double quotes in `grep "$string" file` are not part of the syntax for `grep`; they are discarded by the shell before `grep` runs, and are useful for preventing the shell from messing with whitespace and/or shell metacharacters in the value of `$string`. When you forced in another pair of double quotes, you were grepping for the Message-id inside literal double quotes in the log file, and (of course) not finding any.

Comment: I don't know the `lc`() function in `awk`. To lowercase you probably want to use `tolower()`. Note you can also say `IGNORECASE=1` in the `BEGIN{}` block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
 M="\""$MSGID"\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. And sorry.

I have figured that there were a carriage return in my initial value.

I have changed this like this:

```
MSGID=$(cat ${email} | grep -i 'Message-ID:' |awk '{print $2}' tr -d '\r')
```

Thank you again.